# Jmeter Result Analysis

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I have create test script using jmeter to login and posting a job on a job portal using `10 threads` and `10 sec ramp up periods`.

Can anybody explain me the following result?

```
No. of sample:820   latest sample:3576                Average:654
Deviation: 1003     Throughput: 808.028/minute        median:237
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [The Load Reports](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65153-the-load-reports) guide

> **No. of Samples** is the number of samples with the same label.
>
> **Average** is the average time of a set of results.
>
> **Median** is a number which divides the samples into two equal halves. Half of the samples are smaller than the median, and half are larger. [Some samples may equal the median.] This is a standard statistical measure. The 
>   Median is the same as the 50th Percentile.
>
> **90% Line** (90th Percentile) meaning 90% of the samples took no more than this time.
>
> **Min** is the shortest time for the samples with the same label
>
> **Max** is the longest time for the samples with the same label
>
> **Error %** is the percent of requests with errors
>
> **Throughput** is measured in requests per second/minute/hour. The time unit is chosen so that the displayed rate is at least 1.0. When the throughput is saved to a CSV file, it is expressed in requests/second, i.e. 30.0 requests/minute is saved as 0.5.
>
> **Kb/sec** - throughput measured in Kilobytes per second. Time is in milliseconds.

For other JMeter metrics and terms information see [JMeter Glossary](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please look into the following link,that will answer your all questions
 http://jmeterresults.blogspot.com/2012/07/jmeterunderstanding-summary-report.html